# Validation error for multiple input field Laravel 8

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-8, php-7.4

I have a validation problem regarding multiple input fieldL to store in the database. When I submit, the errors show "additional mark field is required." I try to test dd($request) but the attributes is null. How can I store in DB with multiple input fields?

**Controller**

```
public function StoreAdditionalProcuments(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'additional_remark' => 'required',
    ]);

    foreach ($request->addmore as $key => $value) {
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['additional_remark'] = $value['additional_remark'];
        AssetProcument::create($input);
    }
    
    return redirect('asset')->with('success', 'Maklumat Aset berjaya disimpan.');
}
```

**AssetProcument.php Model**

```
class AssetProcument extends Model
{
    public $fillable = [
      'additional_remark',
    ];
```

**Blade**

```
<form action="{{ route('asset_store_additional_procument') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="col">
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamicTable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Catatan</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:50%"><textarea type="text" name="addmore[][additional_remark]"
                                                    class="form-control"></textarea></td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Tambah</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </body>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-success float-right">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

var i = 0;

$("#add").click(function(){

    ++i;

    $("#dynamicTable").append('<tr><td><textarea type="text" name="addmore['+i+'][additional_remark]"  class="form-control" /></textarea></td>'.'
    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger remove-tr">Remove</button></td></tr>');
});

$(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function(){
     $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('asset_store_additionalprocuments',[AssetController::class,'StoreAdditionalProcuments'])->name('asset_store_additional_procument');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since **additional_remark** input is **addmore[][additional_remark]**, your validation should be like this

```
    $request->validate([
        'addmore.*.additional_remark' => 'required',
    ]);
```

- `*` mark is all indexes of addmore array

Comment: got error for input.. addmore.1.additional_remark field is required,.. i don't know why it brings until 3 addmore required

Comment: do you need to validate additional_remark ? if not, you should remove `$request->validate`.

Comment: yes, i want to validate it first.. if not , i will get the error:Undefined index for additional_remark

Comment: add @ to $value['additional_remark'], like this @$value['additional_remark']. It will set null if undefined

Comment: still got the same.. what is the proper way to make multiple input form in controller ?

Comment: you can dump($request->addmore) to see the input structure, and remove $request->validate, because it no need in your case. I run your code and have a problem here  $("#dynamicTable").append, change '.' to '+' (here is javascript).  I changed it and worked

Comment: maybe problem is Request class, let try request() or \Illuminate\Http\Request